# Simple Product Attributes does not show up as Filter | Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Wordpress Woocommerce Website, When i upload a new **SIMPLE PRODUCT** and add attributes to it such as (Color, Distance, Trap Type, Model, Flush Tank); These does not show up under the Filter. How to achieve this ??

However, when i add attributes to Variation product, all the attributes of variation product shows up under filter.

What code under which file should be changed ?

Sample Product Attributes Image:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "under filter"?

Comment: Side bar, where we use filter by price, color and stuff